# Why is my XML not working?

Tags: magento-1, xml

I'm trying to create a template file for a youtube video and some javascript. It should be added to the catalog/product/view/description block with the following PHP

```
 echo $this->getChildHtml('youtube')
```

This is the XML in my local.xml file that I'm using to try and get this to happen

```
<default>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <reference name="product.info">
                <reference name="product.description">
                    <block type="core/template" name="product.youtube" as="product_youtube" template="catalog/product/view/youtube.phtml" />
                </reference>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</default>
```

The template as of now just has a simple 'hello' but I don't get any output on my product page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove `<default>` and `</default>`

Comment: That actually did the trick, thankyou. Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Sure. Check detailed answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`local.xml` should look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
...

    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="content">
            <reference name="product.info">
                <reference name="product.description">
                    <block type="core/template" name="product.youtube" as="product_youtube" template="catalog/product/view/youtube.phtml" />
                </reference>
            </reference>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>

...
</layout>
```

`<default>` and `<catalog_product_view>` are different handles.

> So you should remove `<default>`

Also use `$this->getChildHtml('product_youtube')` to echo block

Answer (score 1):

Small mistake echo $this->getChildHtml('youtube') should be echo `$this->getChildHtml('product_youtube')`

As your block alias  name is  `product_youtube` *(as="product_youtube")* and trying to call `echo $this->getChildHtml('youtube')`

Also  as Anil mention

```
remove <default> and </default>
```